# How can I show header column on every page in RDLC report?

Tags: c#, rdlc

How can I show header column on every page in RDLC report?

Currently it is showing only on the first page and not on other pages. Which settings do I have to use to show it on all pages?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the tablix -> Properties -> Under the Column preferences -> Repeat header rows on each page

If this will not work, you can try with [the following link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/10/13/repeat-header-and-visible-fixed-header-table.aspx)